# how to include line-numbers in Erlang/Elixir Dbg

Tags: erlang, elixir, dbg

Please how may we include line numbers in the output from Dbg module in Erlang/ Elixir?

I use the https://hexdocs.pm/dbg/ Module for Elixir

```
Dbg.local_call(__MODULE__, [:stack])
Dbg.trace(self(), [:timestamp, :call, :arity])
```

Comment: Why would you think it’s ever possible? Elixir library is just a wrapper around Erlang [`dbg`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html) and I doubt it can ever know about lines, since it’s dealing with _compiled_ AST.

Comment: My question relates to getting dbg line numbers in general, I only pointed out that I'm presently using the elixir wrapper.

Comment: There may be a way to compile to create a map of the debug symbols. I would research that if I were you.